# Calculate top % of variable according to condition

Tags: r, subset

A sample of data is structured as follows:

```
Individ <- data.frame(Participant = c("Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill", 
                                      "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Harry"),
                      Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12),
                      Power = c(400, 250, 180, 500, 300, 450, 600, 512, 300, 500, 450, 200, 402, 210, 130, 520, 310, 451, 608, 582, 390, 570, NA, NA))
```

I calculate a rolling average of `Power` over a two, three and four second period. I know that I can subset each rolling average (accounting for the change in `Participant`) by doing the following:

```
Individ$TwoSec <- ave(Individ$Power, Individ$Participant, 
                          FUN= function(x) rollapply(x, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA) )
Individ$ThreeSec <- ave(Individ$Power, Individ$Participant, 
                          FUN= function(x) rollapply(x, 3, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA) )
Individ$FourSec <- ave(Individ$Power, Individ$Participant, 
                            FUN= function(x) rollapply(x, 4, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA) )
```

I now wish to locate the top 5% of `Power` for each rolling average (`TwoSec`, `ThreeSec` and `FourSec`). How do I do this to account for the change in `Name` and calculate this?

My actual `data.frame` is > 3 million rows, so a quick solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could try

```
library(data.table)
library(RcppRoll)
setDT(Individ)[, lapply(2:4, function(n) {
      r1 <- roll_mean(Power, n, fill=NA)
      r2 <- r1[order(-r1)]
      r2[seq(ceiling(.N*0.05))]}) ,  by = Participant]
```

Comment: Thank you for the `data.table` solution to enhance capacity.

Comment: This also includes the rolling average of Power. I have calculated that OK, I just wish to iterate over each rolling average column (for example, Individ$TwoSec, Individu$ThreeSec) to find the top 5% within each, per participant. Can you please edit or add an answer that omits the rolling average function?

Comment: @user2716568  Could you post that as a new question?

Comment: Yes, I certainly can.

Comment: New questiong is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692701/subset-data-frame-and-calculate-quantile-by-group